# How to iterate through Page Object selectors declared in the constructor (Playwright)

Tags: javascript, node.js, playwright, pageobjects, playwright-test

I've got a web page, where I have defined numbers of filters. Chosing value for a single filter immediately affects shown results. I'm trying to define a function that will iterate through each filter, assert results are updated, then clean the filter. This action will be perform for each of the filters.

The moment of performing the iteration gives me troubles. I'm open to any other approach of defining my selectors, the function as long as it fulfills the goal.

Here's my Page class:

```
import { Page, Locator} from '@playwright/test'

export Class MyPage {
   readonly page: Page;
   readonly filterA: Locator;
   readonly filterB: Locator;
   readonly filterC: Locator;
   ...and so on...
}

constructor(page: Page) {
   this.page = page;
   this.filterA = page.getByTestId('filterA');
   this.filterB = page.getByTestId('filterB');
   this.filterC = page.getByTestId('filterC');
   ...and so on...
}

async applySingleFilter() {

   const filterWithValues = {
        filterA: "1",
        filterB: "2",
        filterC: "3"
   }
 
   let filter: any = null;
   for (filter in filtersWithValues) {
       this.hereMyProblem.selectOption(filtersWithValues[filter])
   }
   // next action that will happen within this method:
   // assert that filter affected shown results
   // perform cleaning the filter
}
```

1. I tried putting my selectors within the constructor into an array, but I cannot refer to them in the this.heresMyProblem.selectOption(filtersWithValues[filter])

Comment: While I don’t recommend doing assertions within page objects, as that’s not a feature/interface of the page but rather what the test wants to do while interacting with the page, for the here’s my problem part, looks like you just need to use bracket [] syntax to dynamically reference the key, or create a function to dynamically return a filter locator rather than listing them statically if there’s a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Try create your own type for this

```
import { Page, Locator } from "@playwright/test";

export type FilterType = "filterA" | "filterB" | "filterC";

export class MyPage {
  readonly page: Page;
  readonly filterLocators: Record<FilterType, Locator>;

  constructor(page: Page) {
    this.page = page;

    this.filterLocators = {
      filterA: page.getByTestId("filterA"),
      filterB: page.getByTestId("filterB"),
      filterC: page.getByTestId("filterC"),
    };
  }

  async applySingleFilter() {
    const filterWithValues: Record<FilterType, string> = {
      filterA: "1",
      filterB: "2",
      filterC: "3",
    };

    // iterate through every locator and apply filter
    for (const key in this.filterLocators) {
      // for every locators select option from filterWithValues
      await this.filterLocators[key].selectOption(filterWithValues[key]);
      // do the rest
    }
  }
}
```